# Limiting displayed results with NSFetchedResultsController and UITableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Having now struggled with this for 2 weeks and finding no adequate tutorials, SO answers any through my own many failed investigations, I felt it best to ask here and see if a good answer could be offered that perhaps could save myself and many others a lot of time and headache!

A lot of guides recommend using NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve data from your Core Data store, especially if you want to display the data in a UITableView. However nearly all tutorials just assume you want to display all the data at once and stop there. As soon as I try to limit the number of cells and implement a 'load more' feature for example, it all starts to fall apart at the seams.

In the following code (implemented in Swift) data is retrieved from an API using AFNetworking and saved to Core Data. The saving of data happens in the *success* block of the AF call.

All of this works, but I am unable to find a successful way of limiting the number of items/cells shown and increasing it as the user scrolls down.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

// TableView Properties
private let cellIdentifier = "SearchResultCellIdentifier"
var refreshController = UIRefreshControl()

// persistant data stores and controllers
private var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?

private var displayCount = 5

// Setup the fetch results controller
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController
{
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 25
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 25

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error)
    {
        println("fetch error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // setup table view delegate and datasource
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    // pull-to-refresh setup
    self.refreshController.addTarget(self, action: "refreshTable:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshController)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

// ask the NSFetchedResultsController for the section
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let info = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return info.numberOfObjects
}

// create and configure each 'UITableViewCell'
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as SearchResultCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

// helper method to configure a UITableViewCell ask NSFetchedResultsController for the model
func configureCell(cell: SearchResultCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Entity
    cell.title.text = entity.name
}

// MARK: NSFetchedResultsController Delegate functions

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
{
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
{
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
}

/* Delegate method called:
        - when a new model is created
        - when an existing model is updated
        - when an existing model is deleted
*/
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
    didChangeObject object: AnyObject,
    atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath,
    forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
    newIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    switch type
    {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            self.configureCell(cell! as SearchResultCell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Move:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
{
    switch type
    {
        case .Insert:
            println("DEBUG: INSERT SECTION")
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break
        case .Delete:
            println("DEBUG: DELETE SECTION")
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

// MARK: Core Data Stack

/**
Save results response from server to CoreData entities
*/
private func saveSearchResultsResponse(response: AnyObject)
{
    self.deleteAllEntities("Entity")
    println("DEBUG: Saving new objects to model")
    // Search results object from response
    if let searchResultsDict = response as? [String: AnyObject]
    {
        if let entities = searchResultsDict["entities"] as? [AnyObject]
        {
            if let attributes = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)?.attributesByName
            {
                // save entities
            }
        }

        }
    }

    // save changes persistent store
    var error : NSError?
    if !(self.managedObjectContext!.save(&error))
    {
        println("ERROR: Error saving model: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func deleteAllEntities(entityName: String)
{
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let allEntityFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    if let savedObjects = self.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(allEntityFetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
    {
        for object in savedObjects
        {
            self.managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(object as NSManagedObject)
        }
        // save changes persistent store
        if !(self.managedObjectContext!.save(&error))
        {
            println("ERROR: Error saving model: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("ERROR: Fetch error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Methods I've tried include:

1. Setting and incrementing the following on the NSFetchedResultsController

   - fetchBatchSize
   - fetchLimit

After a long time playing with these and researching them, they seem like memory optimisations and have no impact on what data the table view shows. Definitely doesn't seem to be the right path.

2. Keeping a count of the number of items I wish to display (e.g. 5). Then incrementing this by an offset (e.g. another 5) every time the user gets to the bottom. Also returning 'count' of the array for *numberOfRowsInSection*. This ends up in *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* crashes and mis-matched Core  Data contexts.

Data is still displayed in cellForRowAtIndexPath using:

```
func configureCell(cell: SearchResultCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let entity = self.fFetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Entity
    ...
}
```

Perhaps this is the right way but I'm implementing it wrong?

3. NSFetchedResultsController is called after updated and results are saved in an array (e.g. [Entity]). This array's count is queried for *numberOfRowsInSection* and data in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* is retrieved from the array item at indexPath.row.

This results in *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* crashes when populating the cell, but once the app is reloaded it displays the data correctly.

I would really like to stick with NSFetchedResultsController because I believe it has some powerful sorting/predicate functionality I would like to take advantage of in my app, but I'm currently at impasse with it. Apologies in advance if this has been definitely answered elsewhere but I was unable to locate such and really appreciate any input.

Comment: Method 2 is the technique that occurred to me when I read your question.  You should just need to keep a "count" as you said and increment this when `willDisplayCellForIndexPath:` is called for row "count-1" and count is < the number of rows in the fetched results controller section (remember to not increment beyond the total count)

Comment: @Paulw11, that was just enough to get me going down the right track. I eventually solved it and got it all working beautifully. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @bamabus perhaps you could share your solution?